# Which meaning of "crucial" fits in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does ''crucial'' mean in this text?

[image]

does it mean ''important''?

Comment: Sort of. Also _fundamental_. The image is that the point is the _crux_, or the support on which the whole structure of the argument is built.

Answer (score 2):

It's more than important. It is the idea that makes the argument work. Without it there is no proof.

The first definition from a Google search is what you want in this case:

[image]